# Cómo llamar a un método desde el main que está en otra clase pero debe pasar por otra clase?

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que realizar un proyecto con las siguientes clases CAlumno, CAsignatura, CConnvocatoria, CEstudios y el main Universidad. En CEstudios tengo una lista de los alumnos que están en una carrera, con la clase CAlumno asigno los datos personales, con CAsignatura el ID con el nombre de la materia que lleva. Mi problema radica en que necesito añadir una convocatoria a un alumno pero llamando un método de la clase CAsignatura y para hacer eso lo que hago es que traigo una lista de los alumnos de una materia para poder poner una nota de su convocatoria (aquí utilizo el ArrayList de CEstudios), si dejo el espacio en blanco es que el alumno no ha hecho ninguna convocatoria si agrego un dato del caso contrario. Lo que no logro hacer es que necesito obtener el alumno, después obtener la asignatura para poder añadir la convocatoria y eso me da un error. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme y de antemano muchas gracias!! (Omití varios métodos para no alargar el programa).

```
 public class Universidad {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Carreras
    CEstudios economia = new CEstudios(506, "Economia");
   
    CEstudios.asignaturas.put(1434, "Estadistica");
    CEstudios.asignaturas.put(1435, "Economía basica");
    CEstudios.asignaturas.put(1436, "Contabilidad");
    CEstudios.asignaturas.put(1437, "Mercado de valores");
    
    //Agregar estudiante

    CAlumno alumno1 = new CAlumno(117730376, "Victoria Barrantes", "San Pedro");
    alumno1.añadirAsignatura(1434, "Estadistica");
    CEstudios.añadirAlumno(alumno1);
     CAlumno alumno2 = new CAlumno(117730376, "Esteban Barrantes", "Santa 
     Marta");
    alumno2.añadirAsignatura(1434, "Estadistica");
    CEstudios.añadirAlumno(alumno2);
     CAlumno alumno3 = new CAlumno(117730376, "Diego Barrantes", "Granadilla");
    alumno3.añadirAsignatura(1434, "Estadistica");
    CEstudios.añadirAlumno(alumno3);

   //Lista de alumnos para poner nota de convocatoria

     System.out.println("ID de asignatura: \t");
            int d = Leer.datoInt();
            int CantiConvo =0;
            for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.size(); i++) {
             if(alumnos.get(i).obtenerIdentificador(d) == true){
               System.out.print(alumnos.get(i).obtenerNombre()+", nota: \t");
                String score = Leer.dato();
                  if (!score.isBlank()) {
                    CantiConvo++;
         alumnos.get(i).asignatura.get(i).asignarConvocatoria(score, CantiConvo); 
                                 
                   }else
               alumnos.get(i).asignatura.get(i).asignarConvocatoria("NP", 0);  
                }
            }
       }
     }
  public class CAlumno {
   int DNI;
   String nombre;
   String direccion;
   CFecha date;


 ArrayList<CAsignatura> asignatura = new ArrayList<>();
   

public CAlumno(int dni, String nom, String dire){
     DNI = ide ;
   nombre = nomb;
     direccion = direc;

}

     public String obtenerNombre(){
   return nombre;
}
 public void añadirAsignatura( int id, String asigna){
   date = new CFecha();
   asignatura.add(new CAsignatura(id, asigna, date));

}
public boolean obtenerIdentificador(int id){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < asignatura.size(); i++) {
        if(asignatura.get(i).obtenerID() == id){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}

 public class CAsignatura {
  int id;
  String nombre;
  CFecha date;

ArrayList<CConvocatoria> convo = new ArrayList<>();

public CAsignatura(int iden, String nom, CFecha fe){
    id = iden;
    nombre = nom;
    date = asignarFecha(fe);
}
 public void asignarConvocatoria(String nota, int cc){
         convo.add(new CConvocatoria(nota, cc));
     } 

 public  class CConvocatoria {
  int numConvo = 0;
  int nota;
  String not;
  String date;

public CConvocatoria(String score,  int Can){
    if (!score.contains("NP")) {
        int con = Integer.parseInt(score);
        asignarNota(con);
    }else{
    not = score;
    }
  numConvo = Can;  

}

public class CEstudios {
 int ID;
 String nombre;

static  ArrayList<CAlumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
static   HashMap<Integer, String> asignaturas = new HashMap<>(); 

public CEstudios(int id, String asig){
 asignarID(id);
 asignarCarrera(asig);
}
static public void añadirAlumno(CAlumno student){
 alumnos.add(student);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que tu problema está aquí:

```
 alumnos.get(i).asignatura.get(i).asignarConvocatoria(score, CantiConvo);
```

Esto solo funcionaria si existen la misma cantidad de Alumnos que de asignatura, ya que ocupas el mismo índice para recorrer ambas y además te saltas asignaturas. Necesitas 2 `for`

Yo pondría el segundo `for` dentro de una función en la clase CAlumno

```
public class CAlumno {
//ETC
     public void asignarConvocatoria(String nota, int cc){
        for (int i = 0; i < asignatura.size(); i++) {
            asignatura.get(i).asignarConvocatoria(nota, cc);
        }
     }  
}
```

Y luego cambiaria la linea que te indico por:

```
 alumnos.get(i).asignarConvocatoria(score, CantiConvo);
```

Comment: Ya lo había intentado de esa forma pero es que el problema me pide que añadirConvocatoria este en la clase CAsignatura, por eso no sé como hacerlo

Comment: @VictorB. es que está en CAsignatura (no lo hemos sacado de ahí), solo que también está en CAlumno. Puedes cambiarle el nombre a `asignarConvocatoriaAllAlumnos` si es que te causara problemas

Comment: Perfecto ya entendí, muchísimas gracias!!